# Write $\,-4i\,$ in polar form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Write $\,-4i\,$ in polar form ${re}^{i\theta}$, with $r$, $\theta\in \mathbb R$, and $\,r\geq0,\;0\leq\theta<2\pi$.

I let $\,z=-4i\,$ first, then get $\,r=\sqrt{0+{4^2}}=4$. However, $\,\tan\theta\,$ is undefined, can I just say $\theta$ is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$? So $z$ in polar form will be  ${4e}^{i\pi/2}$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to plot it in an Argand Diagram, and you will find that it would be $4e^{3i\pi/2}$ instead.

Comment: If you think of it as $4(-i)$ it becomes clearer why the angle is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: Why do you think the tangent is even involved?

Comment: You are almost done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Z=-4i$

That is $Z=4[0+(-1)i]$

You have to find a theta value such that $\sin \theta =-1$ **and** $\cos \theta =0 $

Since $\cos \frac{3\pi}{2}=0$ and $\sin \frac{3\pi}{2}=-1 $

Thus $$Z=4 \left[\cos \frac{3\pi}{2}+i \sin \frac{3\pi}{2} \right]$$

Since $$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta$$

$$Z=4 e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}}$$